# Existence of semi-primitive primes modulo a special class of numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime and $N$ be an integer.

Then $p$ is called *semi-primitive* modulo $N$ if there exists a positive integer $j$ such that $p^j \equiv -1 \pmod{N}$.

Now let $m$ be a positive integer and let $N = \operatorname{rad}\left(\dfrac{p^m-1}{p-1}\right)$, where $\operatorname{rad}(c)$ denotes the product of all the (distinct) prime divisors of an integer $c$.

**Question:** What are the solutions $(p,m)$ to the equation:
$$
p^j \equiv -1 \pmod{\operatorname{rad}\left(\frac{p^m-1}{p-1}\right)}?
$$
That is, for which $(p,m)$ is $p$ semi-primitive modulo $\operatorname{rad}\left(\frac{p^m-1}{p-1}\right)$?

One particular example is the case when $p$ is a Mersenne prime and $m = 4$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The proof is a bit tedious but it turns out that this only works when $m = 2$ or when $p$ is a Mersenne prime and $m = 4$...

Comment: But could you at least show us a sketch of the proof?